# BroadcastReceiver not receiving download complete action

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to capture download complete events, but my BroadcastReceiver is not receiving them. Here is the receiver:

```
public class DownloadListenerService extends BroadcastReceiver {        
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("got here");
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            String downloadPath = intent.getStringExtra(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI);
            editor.putString("downloadPath", downloadPath);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver 
        android:name="com.example.alreadydownloaded.DownloadListenerService" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:enabled="true" android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </application>
```

Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: are you waiting system to send a download complete event or your app.?

Comment: Waiting for system. I am downloading an attachment from Gmail as my test.

Comment: could you try adding category after intent-filer in the manifest.         <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> set exproted="true" and android:enabled="true" in receriver.

Comment: add enable=true outside intent-filter.

Comment: Try doing that in the code just for kicks:context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

Comment: Can you see the file downloaded in SD card? Which device are you trying this on?

Comment: String downloadFilePath = intent.getStringExtra(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI); returns null. I am testing on android N 7.0. I want to get the path of file just downloaded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Use full package name for you receiver like `com.example.DownloadListenerService`
- Add `android:exported="true"` `BroadcastReceiver` can receive messages from sources `outside` its application.
- Change the name of the `Action` in the `intent-filter` to `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`

  ```
      <receiver 
          android:name="com.example.DownloadListenerService"
          android:exported="true" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  ```

**The receiver only will be triggered if was registered from your application using** `registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver,IntentFilter filter);`

***Code to enqueue Download :***

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"));
dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: That also did not work. I'm going to update my question with my new code.

Comment: you know that you will receive broadcasts from the DownloadManager for downloads you requested from you app only, right?

Comment: I did not know that. Is there any way of capturing downloads that aren't requested from the app?

Comment: If you are downloading the file in an external storage you should also use the permission                                                                                   <uses-permission            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>

Comment: why should we add android:exported="true". Is it necessary even if the same application is initiating the downlod?

Comment: String downloadFilePath = intent.getStringExtra(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI); returns null. I am testing on android N 7.0. I want to get the path of file just downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think the action name in your XML is wrong. The docs state that the correct one is: **android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE** not **DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE** - you need to use the constant, not the Java form.

```
<receiver android:name=".DownloadListenerService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:enabled="true" android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: As Simon mentioned below, you've also got the wrong path for your receiver.

Comment: I changed that as well. Still no luck.

Comment: And you put the full path to the DownloadListenerService? Like com.foo.DownloadListenerService?

Comment: try adding android:enabled="true" to your <action> definition. I updated the answer with the action XML.

Comment: That also did not work. I'm going to update my question with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".BroadCast_Service.Download_BroadCast"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1099">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -1):

I think you are calling DownloadManger service from the  IntentService/Service. If so remove it from there and put it into activity.

add permission in android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS" />
```

Answer (score -4):

If the download is based on your app then you need to send a broadcast?

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: he needs to capture download complete events. not sending a new one.