# onReceive does not called after download completed

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to use android downloadManager via this [tutorial](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) . I move broadCastReciever block in a single function, and below is my code:

```
public void downloadManager(){

    boolean is_downloaded = false;

        Log.e("error ", "1");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.e("error ", "2");
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                     Log.e("error ", "3");
                     DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    Log.e("error ", "4");
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        Log.e("error ", "5"); 
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                         if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            // download finished successfully
                            is_downloaded = true;
                            Log.e("error ", "6");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

       getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

     }
```

when I run the project, `is_downloaded` will remains `false`. and in `logcat` I can see just this line:

```
error: 1
```

means that the application control will never reach other `Logs` so

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

will never call. but the image downloads successfully. every thing seems OK, where is the problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you need this variable for, where do you check its value?

Comment: HOw do you launch DownloadManager?

Comment: @Egor He just do to known upto where it working

Comment: @Egor I want to be notified when the download is completed.

Comment: i guess you must register your receiver to receive response in onReceive

Comment: @Vyacheslav I call it in onClockListener.

Comment: @Milad yes, and I did that, ` getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));`

Comment: is the file actially downloaded?

Comment: @Vyacheslav yes the file downloaded completely

Comment: @ShimaErfan Ok its not the answer of your question but I guess you need this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/2101822 see the 3rd one

Comment: are you sure that the activity where the receiver is registered doesn´t get killed in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs absolutely yes

Comment: I can´t see where you have instantiated the `DownloadManager`....Do you only use this static methods or do you have implemented your subclass of `DownloadManager`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS" />`

of course, do not forget this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

if doesn't help try to use BroadcastListener

```
public class DownloadListenerService extends BroadcastReceiver {        
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("got here");
       ///// your code here
        }
    }
}
```

`

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.example.DownloadListenerService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

`

Part of code is from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18789470/1979882

Comment: I added the first permission, and the others existed. no difference

Comment: @ShimaErfan try my another solution

Answer (score 0):

try it through AsyncTask, keep isDownloaded false in onPreExecute() then download the content in doInBackground() and then assign true to isDownloaded in onPostExecute().