# How can I set Receiver in Android?

Tags: android, version

I want to use receiver for auto-update.

When clicking, get download using the URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

And What i want is to run the apk which is downloaded by the intent automatically.

Now, I have to click the apk file one more after download. but I want to do automatically download - run new Apk - delete apk file.

So I'm trying to use receiver but I don't know how to use it.

1st, I added this in manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name=".common.PackageReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
       <data android:scheme="package" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2nd, I make new class.

```
package com.ezcaretech.ecf.common;
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE = "android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String packageName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
        Log.d("TAG", "DOWNLOAD COMPLETE");
    }
  }
}
```

But, after download, the receiver doesn't work anymore.

Thanks

Comment: It may helpful to you check it <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789246/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-download-complete-action>

Comment: Post your download manager code

Comment: You have PackageReceiver.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE and DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, which one you use?

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Thanks!!  As u said, I change the code from intent-startactivity to downloadmanager-dm.enqueue !

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono of course COMPLETE. lol but I change the code T_T Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have statically registered the `BroadcastReceiver` which guarantees that your app will be started when any of those intents you posted is sent.

However, your receiver is only doing something when it gets

`DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`

Comment: Yep Exactly!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I change my code

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.kor_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            DownloadManager dm= (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(strUrl));
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });`
```

and It is working well. Thanks All